# How to Transfer a Party between two Teams Calls, via the Calls Graph API

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a scenario with two group calls.

Call 1 has two Participants   : Party "A" and a call handling BOT (BOT1)

Call 2 has three Participants : Party "B", Party "C" and a call handling BOT (BOT2)

All parties are normal Teams users.

We want to transfer Party B from Call 2 to Call 1 using BOT2

We are trying to do this with the Transfer() function, using example 5 from this reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-transfer?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-5-call-transfer-from-a-group-call

However there is some confusion over what setting we should apply to the parameters.

1. I am assuming that the ID and DisplayName of the transferTarget should be those of Party C
2. What should the ID and Participant ID of the transferee be set to ?
   Note that it is implicit that the ID is *not* that of Party C as given in the tranferTarget block,
   This is because in the example referenced, the two values are different.

I have checked the sample code at
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/
but this does not demonstrate transferring using the transferee block, just the simple case of transferring an user into a call.

Can anyone shed any light on what to set the transferTarget and transferee values to in order to meet the requirements of the scenario described ?

Answer (score 1):

A consultative transfer means that the transferor can inform the person they want to transfer the call to (the transferee), before the transfer is made. This is opposed to transferring the call directly.

**Transfer Target**:   The new party being introduced into a call with
the Transferee.

**participantId** :    The ID of the target participant.

So the ID and display name should be target participant.

also please note the below supported scenario in Group call-

If bot wants to invite another PSTN to join, the P2P call will be escalated into a group call. So far we don't support escalation by adding PSTN. We are working on this feature now and it will be ready soon.
So, here are some scenarios:

- P2P call between Bot and another peer (Teams user, PSTN), bot invites
  another PSTN: Not supported.
- P2P call between Bot and another peer (Teams user, PSTN), bot invites
  another Teams user: Supported.
- P2P call between Bot and another peer (Teams user, PSTN), bot invites
  another bot: Supported.

Reference Document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-transfer?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  That makes sense.  However the confusion arises, because two Teams User IDs are required. One for the transfer Target and one for the transferee.  I assume that the transferee UserID is that of the party to be introduced into the call.  That means that both UserIDs are the same, and refer to the same party.  This is not what the example I linked shows.  The two ids are different.   If the transferTarget UserID is the id of the party being introduced into the call, and is different to the transferee UserID, whose UserID is set as the transferee User ID?

Comment: @MHugh - Are you looking for any further help here or your query has already resolved?

Comment: Currently it appears that whilst it is possible to create a call between a BOT and a PSTN endpoint (using ,AddAsync), it is not possible to Invite a PSTN endpoint into an existing call between two parties.  This is despite the documentation suggesting that it is possible, and indeed showing a sample of how to do it - which does not appear to work.  If you can offer any help regarding when this will be fixed/implemented I would be grateful.

Comment: @MHugh - We are checking the status of the fix/implementation for the above ask with the engineering team. We will let you know once we have any updates on it.

Comment: Currently there is no plan to implement this.
Could you please help by suggesting this feature on - Microsoft Teams · Community[https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472]